# Resizing SVG Icons using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Within the `#pageList` div element, there are six links contained in which when the user clicks the `.togglePL` button, the div element collapses to show the SVG icons only.

When the `#pageList` element is not collapsed, the SVG icons are set at a fixed width and height of 20.

When the user collapses the div to show the icons only, the SVG icons appear really quite small and hard to see on screen.

Is there any way within the Javascript code to keep the icons at a fixed width and height of 20, even if the element `#pageList` is collapsed or not?

I have tried running this line in JS within the else parenthesis but to no prevail: `$('.togglePL a svg').css({width:'20', height:'20'});`

Please find the code attached here:

```js
// ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2021.

// Toggle Page List
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.togglePL').click(function(e) {
        if ($('#pageList').width() == 40) {
            $('.textPL').show();
            $('#pageList').width(164);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'180px', transform: 'none'});
        }
        else {
            $('.textPL').hide();
            $('#pageList').width(40);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'56px', transform: 'rotate(180deg)', transitionDuration:'0.3s'});
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.keyCode | e.which;
        if (e.altKey && keyCode == 80) {
           $('.togglePL').trigger('click')
        }
      })
```

```css
html > body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #1b315e;
}

#navigation > .spacer {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
}

#navigation > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation > a.active {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #15274b;
}

#navigation > a:not(.active):hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #15274b;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation > .navLinks:hover {
    background: #15274b;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

/* Page List */
#pageList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 164px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #15274b;
}

#pageList::before {
    left: 188px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 15% transparent);
}

#pageList::after {
    left: 24px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 15% transparent);
}

#pageList::before, #pageList::after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#pageList > a {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 14px;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#pageList > a > .textPL {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

#pageList > a.active {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #101d38;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#pageList > a:not(.active):hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #101d38;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#pageList > .togglePL {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #101d38;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2021.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Welcome &#8212; Summit &#8212; University of Newcastle</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- External Script -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <!-- Home Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Home workspace" class="active">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M541 229.16l-61-49.83v-77.4a6 6 0 0 0-6-6h-20a6 6 0 0 0-6 6v51.33L308.19 39.14a32.16 32.16 0 0 0-40.38 0L35 229.16a8 8 0 0 0-1.16 11.24l10.1 12.41a8 8 0 0 0 11.2 1.19L96 220.62v243a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h128a16 16 0 0 0 16-16v-128l64 .3V464a16 16 0 0 0 16 16l128-.33a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V220.62L520.86 254a8 8 0 0 0 11.25-1.16l10.1-12.41a8 8 0 0 0-1.21-11.27zm-93.11 218.59h.1l-96 .3V319.88a16.05 16.05 0 0 0-15.95-16l-96-.27a16 16 0 0 0-16.05 16v128.14H128V194.51L288 63.94l160 130.57z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Learning Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Learning workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M356 160H188c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-8c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h168c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm12 52v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H188c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v8c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12h168c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12zm64.7 268h3.3c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H80c-44.2 0-80-35.8-80-80V80C0 35.8 35.8 0 80 0h344c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v368c0 10-6.2 18.6-14.9 22.2-3.6 16.1-4.4 45.6-.4 65.8zM128 384h288V32H128v352zm-96 16c13.4-10 30-16 48-16h16V32H80c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48v320zm372.3 80c-3.1-20.4-2.9-45.2 0-64H80c-64 0-64 64 0 64h324.3z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Student Management Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Student management workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M313.6 288c-28.7 0-42.5 16-89.6 16-47.1 0-60.8-16-89.6-16C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4zM416 464c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16v-41.6C32 365.9 77.9 320 134.4 320c19.6 0 39.1 16 89.6 16 50.4 0 70-16 89.6-16 56.5 0 102.4 45.9 102.4 102.4V464zM224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm0-224c52.9 0 96 43.1 96 96s-43.1 96-96 96-96-43.1-96-96 43.1-96 96-96z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Portal Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Portal workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 496 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M248 8C111 8 0 119 0 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S385 8 248 8zm193.2 152h-82.5c-9-44.4-24.1-82.2-43.2-109.1 55 18.2 100.2 57.9 125.7 109.1zM336 256c0 22.9-1.6 44.2-4.3 64H164.3c-2.7-19.8-4.3-41.1-4.3-64s1.6-44.2 4.3-64h167.4c2.7 19.8 4.3 41.1 4.3 64zM248 40c26.9 0 61.4 44.1 78.1 120H169.9C186.6 84.1 221.1 40 248 40zm-67.5 10.9c-19 26.8-34.2 64.6-43.2 109.1H54.8c25.5-51.2 70.7-90.9 125.7-109.1zM32 256c0-22.3 3.4-43.8 9.7-64h90.5c-2.6 20.5-4.2 41.8-4.2 64s1.5 43.5 4.2 64H41.7c-6.3-20.2-9.7-41.7-9.7-64zm22.8 96h82.5c9 44.4 24.1 82.2 43.2 109.1-55-18.2-100.2-57.9-125.7-109.1zM248 472c-26.9 0-61.4-44.1-78.1-120h156.2c-16.7 75.9-51.2 120-78.1 120zm67.5-10.9c19-26.8 34.2-64.6 43.2-109.1h82.5c-25.5 51.2-70.7 90.9-125.7 109.1zM363.8 320c2.6-20.5 4.2-41.8 4.2-64s-1.5-43.5-4.2-64h90.5c6.3 20.2 9.7 41.7 9.7 64s-3.4 43.8-9.7 64h-90.5z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Administration Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Administration workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M482.696 299.276l-32.61-18.827a195.168 195.168 0 0 0 0-48.899l32.61-18.827c9.576-5.528 14.195-16.902 11.046-27.501-11.214-37.749-31.175-71.728-57.535-99.595-7.634-8.07-19.817-9.836-29.437-4.282l-32.562 18.798a194.125 194.125 0 0 0-42.339-24.48V38.049c0-11.13-7.652-20.804-18.484-23.367-37.644-8.909-77.118-8.91-114.77 0-10.831 2.563-18.484 12.236-18.484 23.367v37.614a194.101 194.101 0 0 0-42.339 24.48L105.23 81.345c-9.621-5.554-21.804-3.788-29.437 4.282-26.36 27.867-46.321 61.847-57.535 99.595-3.149 10.599 1.47 21.972 11.046 27.501l32.61 18.827a195.168 195.168 0 0 0 0 48.899l-32.61 18.827c-9.576 5.528-14.195 16.902-11.046 27.501 11.214 37.748 31.175 71.728 57.535 99.595 7.634 8.07 19.817 9.836 29.437 4.283l32.562-18.798a194.08 194.08 0 0 0 42.339 24.479v37.614c0 11.13 7.652 20.804 18.484 23.367 37.645 8.909 77.118 8.91 114.77 0 10.831-2.563 18.484-12.236 18.484-23.367v-37.614a194.138 194.138 0 0 0 42.339-24.479l32.562 18.798c9.62 5.554 21.803 3.788 29.437-4.283 26.36-27.867 46.321-61.847 57.535-99.595 3.149-10.599-1.47-21.972-11.046-27.501zm-65.479 100.461l-46.309-26.74c-26.988 23.071-36.559 28.876-71.039 41.059v53.479a217.145 217.145 0 0 1-87.738 0v-53.479c-33.621-11.879-43.355-17.395-71.039-41.059l-46.309 26.74c-19.71-22.09-34.689-47.989-43.929-75.958l46.329-26.74c-6.535-35.417-6.538-46.644 0-82.079l-46.329-26.74c9.24-27.969 24.22-53.869 43.929-75.969l46.309 26.76c27.377-23.434 37.063-29.065 71.039-41.069V44.464a216.79 216.79 0 0 1 87.738 0v53.479c33.978 12.005 43.665 17.637 71.039 41.069l46.309-26.76c19.709 22.099 34.689 47.999 43.929 75.969l-46.329 26.74c6.536 35.426 6.538 46.644 0 82.079l46.329 26.74c-9.24 27.968-24.219 53.868-43.929 75.957zM256 160c-52.935 0-96 43.065-96 96s43.065 96 96 96 96-43.065 96-96-43.065-96-96-96zm0 160c-35.29 0-64-28.71-64-64s28.71-64 64-64 64 28.71 64 64-28.71 64-64 64z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <!-- Help -->
                <button title="Help" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M256 340c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28s12.536 28 28 28 28-12.536 28-28-12.536-28-28-28zm7.67-24h-16c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-.381c0-70.343 77.44-63.619 77.44-107.408 0-20.016-17.761-40.211-57.44-40.211-29.144 0-44.265 9.649-59.211 28.692-3.908 4.98-11.054 5.995-16.248 2.376l-13.134-9.15c-5.625-3.919-6.86-11.771-2.645-17.177C185.658 133.514 210.842 116 255.67 116c52.32 0 97.44 29.751 97.44 80.211 0 67.414-77.44 63.849-77.44 107.408V304c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zM256 40c118.621 0 216 96.075 216 216 0 119.291-96.61 216-216 216-119.244 0-216-96.562-216-216 0-119.203 96.602-216 216-216m0-32C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <!-- Quick Links -->
                <button title="Quick links" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M336 0H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v464l192-112 192 112V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zm16 456.287l-160-93.333-160 93.333V48c0-8.822 7.178-16 16-16h288c8.822 0 16 7.178 16 16v408.287z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <!-- Log Out -->
                <button title="Log out" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M160 217.1c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h144v-93.9c0-7.1 8.6-10.7 13.6-5.7l141.6 143.1c6.3 6.3 6.3 16.4 0 22.7L333.6 410.4c-5 5-13.6 1.5-13.6-5.7v-93.9H176c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16v-77.7m-32 0v77.7c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h112v61.9c0 35.5 43 53.5 68.2 28.3l141.7-143c18.8-18.8 18.8-49.2 0-68L356.2 78.9c-25.1-25.1-68.2-7.3-68.2 28.3v61.9H176c-26.5 0-48 21.6-48 48zM0 112v288c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h132c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V112c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h132c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Page List -->
            <div id="pageList">
                <!-- Summit Messages -->
                <a href="#" title="Summit messages">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M569.9 441.1c-.5-.4-22.6-24.2-37.9-54.9 27.5-27.1 44-61.1 44-98.2 0-80-76.5-146.1-176.2-157.9C368.4 72.5 294.3 32 208 32 93.1 32 0 103.6 0 192c0 37 16.5 71 44 98.2-15.3 30.7-37.3 54.5-37.7 54.9-6.3 6.7-8.1 16.5-4.4 25 3.6 8.5 12 14 21.2 14 53.5 0 96.7-20.2 125.2-38.8 9.1 2.1 18.4 3.7 28 4.8 31.5 57.5 105.5 98 191.8 98 20.8 0 40.8-2.4 59.8-6.8 28.5 18.5 71.6 38.8 125.2 38.8 9.2 0 17.5-5.5 21.2-14 3.6-8.5 1.9-18.3-4.4-25zM155.4 314l-13.2-3-11.4 7.4c-20.1 13.1-50.5 28.2-87.7 32.5 8.8-11.3 20.2-27.6 29.5-46.4L83 283.7l-16.5-16.3C50.7 251.9 32 226.2 32 192c0-70.6 79-128 176-128s176 57.4 176 128-79 128-176 128c-17.7 0-35.4-2-52.6-6zm289.8 100.4l-11.4-7.4-13.2 3.1c-17.2 4-34.9 6-52.6 6-65.1 0-122-25.9-152.4-64.3C326.9 348.6 416 278.4 416 192c0-9.5-1.3-18.7-3.3-27.7C488.1 178.8 544 228.7 544 288c0 34.2-18.7 59.9-34.5 75.4L493 379.7l10.3 20.7c9.4 18.9 20.8 35.2 29.5 46.4-37.1-4.2-67.5-19.4-87.6-32.4z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Summit Messages</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Dashboard -->
                <a href="#" title="Dashboard">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M504 416H32V72c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8H8c-4.42 0-8 3.58-8 8v360c0 8.84 7.16 16 16 16h488c4.42 0 8-3.58 8-8v-16c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8zM98.34 263.03c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l11.31 11.31c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l72.69-72.01 84.69 84.69c6.25 6.25 16.38 6.25 22.63 0l93.53-93.53 44.04 44.04c4.95 4.95 11.03 7.16 17 7.16 12.48 0 24.46-9.7 24.46-24.34V112.19c0-8.94-7.25-16.19-16.19-16.19H344.34c-21.64 0-32.47 26.16-17.17 41.46l44.71 44.71-82.22 82.22-84.63-84.63c-6.23-6.23-16.32-6.25-22.57-.05l-84.12 83.32zM362.96 128H448v85.04L362.96 128z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Help -->
                <a href="#" title="Help">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M256 340c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28s12.536 28 28 28 28-12.536 28-28-12.536-28-28-28zm7.67-24h-16c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-.381c0-70.343 77.44-63.619 77.44-107.408 0-20.016-17.761-40.211-57.44-40.211-29.144 0-44.265 9.649-59.211 28.692-3.908 4.98-11.054 5.995-16.248 2.376l-13.134-9.15c-5.625-3.919-6.86-11.771-2.645-17.177C185.658 133.514 210.842 116 255.67 116c52.32 0 97.44 29.751 97.44 80.211 0 67.414-77.44 63.849-77.44 107.408V304c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zM256 40c118.621 0 216 96.075 216 216 0 119.291-96.61 216-216 216-119.244 0-216-96.562-216-216 0-119.203 96.602-216 216-216m0-32C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Help</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Notices -->
                <a href="#" title="Notices">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M552 64H88c-13.234 0-24 10.767-24 24v8H24c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24v280c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h504c13.233 0 24-10.767 24-24V88c0-13.233-10.767-24-24-24zM32 400V128h32v272c0 8.822-7.178 16-16 16s-16-7.178-16-16zm512 16H93.258A47.897 47.897 0 0 0 96 400V96h448v320zm-404-96h168c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V140c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12H140c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v168c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12zm20-160h128v128H160V160zm-32 212v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h168c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm224 0v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0-64v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0-128v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0 64v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Notices</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Timetable -->
                <a href="#" title="Timetable">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M400 64h-48V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-8c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H128V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-8c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V112c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM48 96h352c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v48H32v-48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16zm352 384H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V192h384v272c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16zM148 320h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm-96 96h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm-96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm192 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Timetable</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Welcome -->
                <a href="#" title="Welcome" class="active">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M638.9 209.7l-8-13.9c-2.2-3.8-7.1-5.1-10.9-2.9l-108 63V240c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48H320v62.2c0 16-10.9 30.8-26.6 33.3-20 3.3-37.4-12.2-37.4-31.6v-94.3c0-13.8 7.1-26.6 18.8-33.9l33.4-20.9c11.4-7.1 24.6-10.9 38.1-10.9h103.2l118.5-67c3.8-2.2 5.2-7.1 3-10.9l-8-14c-2.2-3.8-7.1-5.2-10.9-3l-111 63h-94.7c-19.5 0-38.6 5.5-55.1 15.8l-33.5 20.9c-17.5 11-28.7 28.6-32.2 48.5l-62.5 37c-21.6 13-35.1 36.7-35.1 61.9v38.6L4 357.1c-3.8 2.2-5.2 7.1-3 10.9l8 13.9c2.2 3.8 7.1 5.2 10.9 3L160 305.3v-57.2c0-14 7.5-27.2 19.4-34.4l44.6-26.4v65.9c0 33.4 24.3 63.3 57.6 66.5 38.1 3.7 70.4-26.3 70.4-63.7v-32h112c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v32c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16h-24v36c0 19.8-16 35.8-35.8 35.8h-16.1v16c0 22.2-18 40.2-40.2 40.2H238.5l-115.6 67.3c-3.8 2.2-5.1 7.1-2.9 10.9l8 13.8c2.2 3.8 7.1 5.1 10.9 2.9L247.1 448h100.8c34.8 0 64-24.8 70.8-57.7 30.4-6.7 53.3-33.9 53.3-66.3v-4.7c13.6-2.3 24.6-10.6 31.8-21.7l132.2-77c3.8-2.2 5.1-7.1 2.9-10.9z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Welcome</span>
                </a>
                <button title="Expand/collapse the page selectors [ alt + p ]" class="togglePL">
                    <svg width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 256 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M238.475 475.535l7.071-7.07c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L50.053 256 245.546 60.506c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971l-7.071-7.07c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.97 0L10.454 247.515c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l211.051 211.05c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.97-.001z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../JS/setting.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Internal Script -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the hardcoded width/height from the SVG tags, and set those with CSS?

Comment: No not as yet, will give that a go.

Comment: It didn't work, how would you go about that in css?

Comment: Please! [Create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should try to remove the hardcoded size attributes and work with viewbox `viewBox="0 0 50 50"` you might want to adjust the numbers for size. See syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It acquired the width according to with of its container, you need to set with to `50` using `$('#pageList').width(50);` for a better size of SVG icons.

or simply add the custom class when the sidebar is collapsed and then decrease the padding of `a` to make some space for SVG icons.
Like:

```
#pageList.opened a{
padding: 28px 8px;
}
```

```js
// Toggle Page List
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.togglePL').click(function(e) {
        if ($('#pageList').width() == 40) {
            $('.textPL').show();
            $('#pageList').width(164).removeClass('opened');
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'180px', transform: 'none'});
        }
        else {
            $('.textPL').hide();
            $('#pageList').width(40).addClass('opened');
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'56px', transform: 'rotate(180deg)', transitionDuration:'0.3s'});
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.keyCode | e.which;
        if (e.altKey && keyCode == 80) {
           $('.togglePL').trigger('click')
        }
      })
```

```css
html > body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #1b315e;
}

#navigation > .spacer {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
}

#navigation > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation > a.active {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #15274b;
}

#navigation > a:not(.active):hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #15274b;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation > .navLinks:hover {
    background: #15274b;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

/* Page List */
#pageList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 164px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #15274b;
}

#pageList::before {
    left: 188px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 15% transparent);
}

#pageList::after {
    left: 24px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 15% transparent);
}

#pageList::before, #pageList::after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#pageList > a {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 14px;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#pageList > a > .textPL {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

#pageList > a.active {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #101d38;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#pageList > a:not(.active):hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #101d38;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#pageList > .togglePL {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #101d38;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#pageList.opened a{
padding: 28px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2021.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Welcome &#8212; Summit &#8212; University of Newcastle</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- External Script -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <!-- Home Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Home workspace" class="active">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M541 229.16l-61-49.83v-77.4a6 6 0 0 0-6-6h-20a6 6 0 0 0-6 6v51.33L308.19 39.14a32.16 32.16 0 0 0-40.38 0L35 229.16a8 8 0 0 0-1.16 11.24l10.1 12.41a8 8 0 0 0 11.2 1.19L96 220.62v243a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h128a16 16 0 0 0 16-16v-128l64 .3V464a16 16 0 0 0 16 16l128-.33a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V220.62L520.86 254a8 8 0 0 0 11.25-1.16l10.1-12.41a8 8 0 0 0-1.21-11.27zm-93.11 218.59h.1l-96 .3V319.88a16.05 16.05 0 0 0-15.95-16l-96-.27a16 16 0 0 0-16.05 16v128.14H128V194.51L288 63.94l160 130.57z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Learning Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Learning workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M356 160H188c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-8c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h168c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm12 52v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H188c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v8c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12h168c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12zm64.7 268h3.3c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v8c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H80c-44.2 0-80-35.8-80-80V80C0 35.8 35.8 0 80 0h344c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v368c0 10-6.2 18.6-14.9 22.2-3.6 16.1-4.4 45.6-.4 65.8zM128 384h288V32H128v352zm-96 16c13.4-10 30-16 48-16h16V32H80c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48v320zm372.3 80c-3.1-20.4-2.9-45.2 0-64H80c-64 0-64 64 0 64h324.3z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Student Management Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Student management workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M313.6 288c-28.7 0-42.5 16-89.6 16-47.1 0-60.8-16-89.6-16C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4zM416 464c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16v-41.6C32 365.9 77.9 320 134.4 320c19.6 0 39.1 16 89.6 16 50.4 0 70-16 89.6-16 56.5 0 102.4 45.9 102.4 102.4V464zM224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm0-224c52.9 0 96 43.1 96 96s-43.1 96-96 96-96-43.1-96-96 43.1-96 96-96z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Portal Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Portal workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 496 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M248 8C111 8 0 119 0 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S385 8 248 8zm193.2 152h-82.5c-9-44.4-24.1-82.2-43.2-109.1 55 18.2 100.2 57.9 125.7 109.1zM336 256c0 22.9-1.6 44.2-4.3 64H164.3c-2.7-19.8-4.3-41.1-4.3-64s1.6-44.2 4.3-64h167.4c2.7 19.8 4.3 41.1 4.3 64zM248 40c26.9 0 61.4 44.1 78.1 120H169.9C186.6 84.1 221.1 40 248 40zm-67.5 10.9c-19 26.8-34.2 64.6-43.2 109.1H54.8c25.5-51.2 70.7-90.9 125.7-109.1zM32 256c0-22.3 3.4-43.8 9.7-64h90.5c-2.6 20.5-4.2 41.8-4.2 64s1.5 43.5 4.2 64H41.7c-6.3-20.2-9.7-41.7-9.7-64zm22.8 96h82.5c9 44.4 24.1 82.2 43.2 109.1-55-18.2-100.2-57.9-125.7-109.1zM248 472c-26.9 0-61.4-44.1-78.1-120h156.2c-16.7 75.9-51.2 120-78.1 120zm67.5-10.9c19-26.8 34.2-64.6 43.2-109.1h82.5c-25.5 51.2-70.7 90.9-125.7 109.1zM363.8 320c2.6-20.5 4.2-41.8 4.2-64s-1.5-43.5-4.2-64h90.5c6.3 20.2 9.7 41.7 9.7 64s-3.4 43.8-9.7 64h-90.5z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- Administration Workspace -->
                <a href="#" title="Administration workspace">
                    <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M482.696 299.276l-32.61-18.827a195.168 195.168 0 0 0 0-48.899l32.61-18.827c9.576-5.528 14.195-16.902 11.046-27.501-11.214-37.749-31.175-71.728-57.535-99.595-7.634-8.07-19.817-9.836-29.437-4.282l-32.562 18.798a194.125 194.125 0 0 0-42.339-24.48V38.049c0-11.13-7.652-20.804-18.484-23.367-37.644-8.909-77.118-8.91-114.77 0-10.831 2.563-18.484 12.236-18.484 23.367v37.614a194.101 194.101 0 0 0-42.339 24.48L105.23 81.345c-9.621-5.554-21.804-3.788-29.437 4.282-26.36 27.867-46.321 61.847-57.535 99.595-3.149 10.599 1.47 21.972 11.046 27.501l32.61 18.827a195.168 195.168 0 0 0 0 48.899l-32.61 18.827c-9.576 5.528-14.195 16.902-11.046 27.501 11.214 37.748 31.175 71.728 57.535 99.595 7.634 8.07 19.817 9.836 29.437 4.283l32.562-18.798a194.08 194.08 0 0 0 42.339 24.479v37.614c0 11.13 7.652 20.804 18.484 23.367 37.645 8.909 77.118 8.91 114.77 0 10.831-2.563 18.484-12.236 18.484-23.367v-37.614a194.138 194.138 0 0 0 42.339-24.479l32.562 18.798c9.62 5.554 21.803 3.788 29.437-4.283 26.36-27.867 46.321-61.847 57.535-99.595 3.149-10.599-1.47-21.972-11.046-27.501zm-65.479 100.461l-46.309-26.74c-26.988 23.071-36.559 28.876-71.039 41.059v53.479a217.145 217.145 0 0 1-87.738 0v-53.479c-33.621-11.879-43.355-17.395-71.039-41.059l-46.309 26.74c-19.71-22.09-34.689-47.989-43.929-75.958l46.329-26.74c-6.535-35.417-6.538-46.644 0-82.079l-46.329-26.74c9.24-27.969 24.22-53.869 43.929-75.969l46.309 26.76c27.377-23.434 37.063-29.065 71.039-41.069V44.464a216.79 216.79 0 0 1 87.738 0v53.479c33.978 12.005 43.665 17.637 71.039 41.069l46.309-26.76c19.709 22.099 34.689 47.999 43.929 75.969l-46.329 26.74c6.536 35.426 6.538 46.644 0 82.079l46.329 26.74c-9.24 27.968-24.219 53.868-43.929 75.957zM256 160c-52.935 0-96 43.065-96 96s43.065 96 96 96 96-43.065 96-96-43.065-96-96-96zm0 160c-35.29 0-64-28.71-64-64s28.71-64 64-64 64 28.71 64 64-28.71 64-64 64z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <!-- Help -->
                <button title="Help" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M256 340c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28s12.536 28 28 28 28-12.536 28-28-12.536-28-28-28zm7.67-24h-16c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-.381c0-70.343 77.44-63.619 77.44-107.408 0-20.016-17.761-40.211-57.44-40.211-29.144 0-44.265 9.649-59.211 28.692-3.908 4.98-11.054 5.995-16.248 2.376l-13.134-9.15c-5.625-3.919-6.86-11.771-2.645-17.177C185.658 133.514 210.842 116 255.67 116c52.32 0 97.44 29.751 97.44 80.211 0 67.414-77.44 63.849-77.44 107.408V304c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zM256 40c118.621 0 216 96.075 216 216 0 119.291-96.61 216-216 216-119.244 0-216-96.562-216-216 0-119.203 96.602-216 216-216m0-32C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <!-- Quick Links -->
                <button title="Quick links" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M336 0H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v464l192-112 192 112V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zm16 456.287l-160-93.333-160 93.333V48c0-8.822 7.178-16 16-16h288c8.822 0 16 7.178 16 16v408.287z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <!-- Log Out -->
                <button title="Log out" class="navLinks">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M160 217.1c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h144v-93.9c0-7.1 8.6-10.7 13.6-5.7l141.6 143.1c6.3 6.3 6.3 16.4 0 22.7L333.6 410.4c-5 5-13.6 1.5-13.6-5.7v-93.9H176c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16v-77.7m-32 0v77.7c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h112v61.9c0 35.5 43 53.5 68.2 28.3l141.7-143c18.8-18.8 18.8-49.2 0-68L356.2 78.9c-25.1-25.1-68.2-7.3-68.2 28.3v61.9H176c-26.5 0-48 21.6-48 48zM0 112v288c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h132c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V112c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h132c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-8c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Page List -->
            <div id="pageList">
                <!-- Summit Messages -->
                <a href="#" title="Summit messages">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M569.9 441.1c-.5-.4-22.6-24.2-37.9-54.9 27.5-27.1 44-61.1 44-98.2 0-80-76.5-146.1-176.2-157.9C368.4 72.5 294.3 32 208 32 93.1 32 0 103.6 0 192c0 37 16.5 71 44 98.2-15.3 30.7-37.3 54.5-37.7 54.9-6.3 6.7-8.1 16.5-4.4 25 3.6 8.5 12 14 21.2 14 53.5 0 96.7-20.2 125.2-38.8 9.1 2.1 18.4 3.7 28 4.8 31.5 57.5 105.5 98 191.8 98 20.8 0 40.8-2.4 59.8-6.8 28.5 18.5 71.6 38.8 125.2 38.8 9.2 0 17.5-5.5 21.2-14 3.6-8.5 1.9-18.3-4.4-25zM155.4 314l-13.2-3-11.4 7.4c-20.1 13.1-50.5 28.2-87.7 32.5 8.8-11.3 20.2-27.6 29.5-46.4L83 283.7l-16.5-16.3C50.7 251.9 32 226.2 32 192c0-70.6 79-128 176-128s176 57.4 176 128-79 128-176 128c-17.7 0-35.4-2-52.6-6zm289.8 100.4l-11.4-7.4-13.2 3.1c-17.2 4-34.9 6-52.6 6-65.1 0-122-25.9-152.4-64.3C326.9 348.6 416 278.4 416 192c0-9.5-1.3-18.7-3.3-27.7C488.1 178.8 544 228.7 544 288c0 34.2-18.7 59.9-34.5 75.4L493 379.7l10.3 20.7c9.4 18.9 20.8 35.2 29.5 46.4-37.1-4.2-67.5-19.4-87.6-32.4z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Summit Messages</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Dashboard -->
                <a href="#" title="Dashboard">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M504 416H32V72c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8H8c-4.42 0-8 3.58-8 8v360c0 8.84 7.16 16 16 16h488c4.42 0 8-3.58 8-8v-16c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8zM98.34 263.03c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l11.31 11.31c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l72.69-72.01 84.69 84.69c6.25 6.25 16.38 6.25 22.63 0l93.53-93.53 44.04 44.04c4.95 4.95 11.03 7.16 17 7.16 12.48 0 24.46-9.7 24.46-24.34V112.19c0-8.94-7.25-16.19-16.19-16.19H344.34c-21.64 0-32.47 26.16-17.17 41.46l44.71 44.71-82.22 82.22-84.63-84.63c-6.23-6.23-16.32-6.25-22.57-.05l-84.12 83.32zM362.96 128H448v85.04L362.96 128z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Help -->
                <a href="#" title="Help">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M256 340c-15.464 0-28 12.536-28 28s12.536 28 28 28 28-12.536 28-28-12.536-28-28-28zm7.67-24h-16c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-.381c0-70.343 77.44-63.619 77.44-107.408 0-20.016-17.761-40.211-57.44-40.211-29.144 0-44.265 9.649-59.211 28.692-3.908 4.98-11.054 5.995-16.248 2.376l-13.134-9.15c-5.625-3.919-6.86-11.771-2.645-17.177C185.658 133.514 210.842 116 255.67 116c52.32 0 97.44 29.751 97.44 80.211 0 67.414-77.44 63.849-77.44 107.408V304c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zM256 40c118.621 0 216 96.075 216 216 0 119.291-96.61 216-216 216-119.244 0-216-96.562-216-216 0-119.203 96.602-216 216-216m0-32C119.043 8 8 119.083 8 256c0 136.997 111.043 248 248 248s248-111.003 248-248C504 119.083 392.957 8 256 8z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Help</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Notices -->
                <a href="#" title="Notices">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M552 64H88c-13.234 0-24 10.767-24 24v8H24c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24v280c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h504c13.233 0 24-10.767 24-24V88c0-13.233-10.767-24-24-24zM32 400V128h32v272c0 8.822-7.178 16-16 16s-16-7.178-16-16zm512 16H93.258A47.897 47.897 0 0 0 96 400V96h448v320zm-404-96h168c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V140c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12H140c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v168c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12zm20-160h128v128H160V160zm-32 212v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h168c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H140c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm224 0v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0-64v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0-128v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12zm0 64v-8c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h136c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v8c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12H364c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Notices</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Timetable -->
                <a href="#" title="Timetable">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M400 64h-48V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-8c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H128V12c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-8c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v52H48C21.5 64 0 85.5 0 112v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V112c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM48 96h352c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v48H32v-48c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16zm352 384H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V192h384v272c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16zM148 320h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm-96 96h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm-96 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12zm192 0h-40c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-40c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Timetable</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Welcome -->
                <a href="#" title="Welcome" class="active">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M638.9 209.7l-8-13.9c-2.2-3.8-7.1-5.1-10.9-2.9l-108 63V240c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48H320v62.2c0 16-10.9 30.8-26.6 33.3-20 3.3-37.4-12.2-37.4-31.6v-94.3c0-13.8 7.1-26.6 18.8-33.9l33.4-20.9c11.4-7.1 24.6-10.9 38.1-10.9h103.2l118.5-67c3.8-2.2 5.2-7.1 3-10.9l-8-14c-2.2-3.8-7.1-5.2-10.9-3l-111 63h-94.7c-19.5 0-38.6 5.5-55.1 15.8l-33.5 20.9c-17.5 11-28.7 28.6-32.2 48.5l-62.5 37c-21.6 13-35.1 36.7-35.1 61.9v38.6L4 357.1c-3.8 2.2-5.2 7.1-3 10.9l8 13.9c2.2 3.8 7.1 5.2 10.9 3L160 305.3v-57.2c0-14 7.5-27.2 19.4-34.4l44.6-26.4v65.9c0 33.4 24.3 63.3 57.6 66.5 38.1 3.7 70.4-26.3 70.4-63.7v-32h112c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v32c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16h-24v36c0 19.8-16 35.8-35.8 35.8h-16.1v16c0 22.2-18 40.2-40.2 40.2H238.5l-115.6 67.3c-3.8 2.2-5.1 7.1-2.9 10.9l8 13.8c2.2 3.8 7.1 5.1 10.9 2.9L247.1 448h100.8c34.8 0 64-24.8 70.8-57.7 30.4-6.7 53.3-33.9 53.3-66.3v-4.7c13.6-2.3 24.6-10.6 31.8-21.7l132.2-77c3.8-2.2 5.1-7.1 2.9-10.9z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="textPL">Welcome</span>
                </a>
                <button title="Expand/collapse the page selectors [ alt + p ]" class="togglePL">
                    <svg width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 256 512">
                        <g style="fill: #fff;">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M238.475 475.535l7.071-7.07c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L50.053 256 245.546 60.506c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971l-7.071-7.07c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.97 0L10.454 247.515c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l211.051 211.05c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.97-.001z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../JS/setting.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Internal Script -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem happened because you specified the width and height as inline property in your SVG element.
in CSS the inline properties have more Priority;
so try to remove inline styles and it should work